# Reading a file in a shell script and selecting a section of the line

Tags: bash, shell, cut

This is probably pretty basic, I want to read in a occurrence file.

Then the program should find all occurrences of `"CallTilEdb"` in the file `Hendelse.logg`:

```
CallTilEdb         8
CallCustomer       9
CallTilEdb         4
CustomerChk        10
CustomerChk        15
CallTilEdb         16
```

and sum up then right column. For this case it would be 8 + 4 + 16, so the output I would want would be `28`.

I'm not sure how to do this, and this is as far as I have gotten with `vistid.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -t filename=hendelse.logg
declare -t occurance="$1"
declare -i sumTime=0

while read -r line
do
    if [ "$occurance" = $(cut -f1 line) ]       #line 10
    then
        sumTime+=$(cut -f2 line)
    fi
done < "$filename"
```

so the execution in terminal would be

```
vistid.sh CallTilEdb
```

but the error I get now is:

```
/home/user/bin/vistid.sh: line 10: [: unary operator expected
```

Comment: What is an "occurance feks"?

Comment: @John I tried to clean up the question, that term is gone.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I meant to write occurance fex.(Occurance for example)

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks :) I'm quite new to Shell Scripting and therefore my terminology is a bit off :P Sorry for this.

Comment: @Patidati: in American and British English, neither "feks" nor "fex" is generally understood to mean "for example."  People usually write "e.g.," "ex.," or "for example."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a nice approach, but maybe you could use `awk` to do the same thing... quite faster!

```
$ awk -v par="CallTilEdb" '$1==par {sum+=$2} END {print sum+0}' hendelse.logg
28
```

It may look a bit weird if you haven't used awk so far, but here is what it does:

- `-v par="CallTilEdb"` provide an argument to `awk`, so that we can use `par` as a variable in the script. You could also do `-v par="$1"` if you want to use a variable provided to the script as parameter.
- `$1==par {sum+=$2}` this means: if the first field is the same as the content of the variable `par`, then add the second column's value into the counter `sum`.
- `END {print sum+0}` this means: once you are done from processing the file, print the content of `sum`. The `+0` makes `awk` print `0` in case `sum` was not set... that is, if nothing was found.

---

In case you really want to make it with bash, you can use `read` with two parameters, so that you don't have to make use of `cut` to handle the values, together with some [arithmetic operations](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Perform_arithmetic_operations) to sum the values:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -t filename=hendelse.logg
declare -t occurance="$1"
declare -i sumTime=0

while read -r name value                  # read both values with -r for safety
do
    if [ "$occurance" == "$name" ]; then  # string comparison
       ((sumTime+=$value))                # sum
    fi
done < "$filename"

echo "sum: $sumTime"
```

So that it works like this:

```
$ ./vistid.sh CallTilEdb
sum: 28
$ ./vistid.sh CustomerChk
sum: 25
```

Comment: Thanks! I will be trying both approaches for the practice of it, very nice and simple explanation, actually make sense :)!

Comment: @Patidati nice to read that :) Note I added a bash version, because you can make use of `read -r name value` and get rid of all those `cut`s.

Comment: That worked (the bash version) Thanks so much :) Will check out the awk version now ;)

Comment: Quick question, could you explain the read -r? man read shows it removes any current binding for keyseq, but what is keyseq?

Comment: @Patidati sure! From [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001), "The `-r` option to `read` prevents backslash interpretation (usually used as a backslash newline pair, to continue over multiple lines).  Without this option, any backslashes in the input will be discarded.  You should almost always use the `-r` option with read." So it is a security measure to prevent weird characters in the file causing weird behaviours.

Comment: Once again, perfectly explained :) Thank you :)!

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to change the way you call cut:

```
$( echo $line | cut -f1 )
```

in line 10 you miss the evaluation:

```
if [ "$occurance" = $( echo $line | cut -f1 ) ]
```

you can then sum by doing:

```
sumTime=$[ $sumTime + $( echo $line | cut -f2 ) ]
```

But you can also use a different approach and put the line values in an array, the final script will look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -t filename=prova
declare -t occurance="$1"
declare -i sumTime=0

while read -a line
do
    if [ "$occurance" = ${line[0]} ]
    then
        sumTime=$[ $sumtime + ${line[1]} ]
    fi
done < "$filename"

echo $sumTime
```

Comment: Just wanted to quickly post that i'm reading these and trying it out ;)

Comment: Ok :) Trying the first apporach without the array, will be trying the array approach afterwards.
The problem now is that on line 10 i get this error:
<Too many arguments>
On line 12:
<unexpected EOF while looking for matching `]'>

Answer (score 0):

Awk translation to script:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -t filename=hendelse.logg
declare -t occurance="$1"
declare -i sumTime=0

sumtime=$(awk -v entry=$occurance '
                                   $1==entry{time+=$NF+0}
                                  END{print time+0}' $filename)
```

Comment: No need to declare `time`. It is defined once you start using it. See my approach.

Comment: Hi, if no entry is found throws "void" result. +1 anyway

Comment: True! For that case it is convenient to use `END {print time+0}` to assure you will print either `time` or `0`.

Answer (score 0):

For the reference,

```
id="CallTilEdb"
file="Hendelse.logg"

sum=$(echo "0 $(sed -n "s/^$id[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)/\1 +/p" < "$file") p" | dc)
echo SUM: $sum
```

prints

```
SUM: 28
```

- the `sed` extract numbers from a lines containing the given id, such `CallTilEdb`
- and prints them in the format `number +`
- the `echo` prepares a string such `0 8 + 16 + 4 + p` what is calculation in RPN format
- the dc do the calculation

another variant:

```
sum=$(sed -n "s/^$id[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)/\1/p" < "$file" | paste -sd+ - | bc)
#or
sum=$(grep -oP "^$id\D*\K\d+" < "$file" | paste -sd+ - | bc)
```

- the sed (or the grep) extracts and prints only the numbers
- the paste make a string like `number + number + number` (`-d+` is a delimiter)
- the `bc` do the calculation

or perl

```
sum=$(perl -slanE '$s+=$F[1] if /^$id/}{say $s' -- -id="$id" "$file")
sum=$(ID="CallTilEdb" perl -lanE '$s+=$F[1] if /^$ENV{ID}/}{say $s' "$file")
```