# Bash: cut won't cut first line when reading from file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cut

I am trying to make a shell-script in bash that takes a log file as an argument and then asks for an event to search for in the file. The log file looks like this:

```
CallTilEdb  8
CallCustomer    9
CallTilEdb  4
CustomerChk 10
CustomerChk 15
CallTilEdb  16
```

So first comes the name of an event, then the time it took, seperated by a tab. The point of the bash script is to search for the specified event and add the total amount of time spent on that event. My script so far looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i sumTime=0

echo "Which event do you want to search for?"
read event

while read -r line
do
    echo $line; cut -f1
    if [ $(echo $line; cut -f1) == $event ];then
        echo $line; cut -f2
    fi
done < $1


echo "The sum is $sumTime"
```

I am not adding anything right now, because first I need to solve this problem I have with cut. The problem I have is, it will not cut the first line, but it will cut all other lines the way I want. This messes up my if-statement, giving it too many arguments. Here's the result of running my script right now:

```
Which event do you want to search for?
CallTilEdb
CallTilEdb 8 #first line of the file
CallCustomer
CallTilEdb
CustomerChk
CustomerChk
CallTilEdb
bin/vistid.sh: line 11: [: too many arguments
The sum is 0
```

I'm quite new to bash so it might be a stupid question, but I just can't make sense of it. Any guide to how I fix this is really appreciated.

PS: echoing f1 right now is just to see what causes the error.

Comment: Isn't this script the one posted in [Reading a file in a shell script and selecting a section of the line](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25742693/)? Also, `$(echo $line; cut -f1)` does not make many sense - you need a pipe, not a `;`. See my answer on that question for how to handle two elements per line.

Comment: `;` and `|` are not the same. Also, use double quotes in `[ ... ]`, or use `[[ ... ]]`.

Comment: @fedorqui It is indeed the same script but kind of a different problem. I could use your solution from there but the assignment hinted i should use cut and the fact that it works for every line but the first one annoys me so much I really want to make it work with cut.

And about the ; and | I definitely need to read more up on that, cause I haven't really understood what to use when yet.

Comment: Roughly: `command1 ; command2` executes `command1` and then `command2`, no matter what happened to `command1`. On the contrary, `command1 | command2` makes `command2` work with the output of `command1`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `read` itself to split the line into two fields.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i sumTime=0

echo "Which event do you want to search for?"
read event

while read -r column1 column2
do
    if [ "$column1" = "$event" ];then
        sumTime+=$column2
    fi
done < "$1"


echo "The sum is $sumTime"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can basically use a single line to implement the counting loop, like

```
$ grep CallTilEdb data | tr -s ' ' |  cut -f 2 -d ' ' | awk '{total = total + $1}END{print "The sum is " total}'
The sum is 28
```

Comment: Or directly `awk -v par="CallTilEdb" '$1==par {sum+=$2} END {print sum+0}'` as I suggested in the "kind of duplicate question" http://stackoverflow.com/q/25742693/

Comment: Yes... a bit weird. Not sure if it is a duplicate, but certainly is the same script!

Comment: "Homework", we were given some assigments as practice :) But we were given quite little information on how to use some of the commands, and encouraged to find it out on our own/via searching.